# Android Animation - Relative layout slide in when visible

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I am working on an Android app. 

In my activity, I have a `Button` and an invisible "card" view in the middle of the screen (think it like a single Google Now card kind of thing) . The card's `visibility` property is `GONE` by default, and I implemented the button's `OnClickListener` to set the card's visibility to `VISIBLE` so the card can show up when user clicks the button.

Currently, the card just "appear" without any animation, which feels bad. I want the card could do something like sliding up and show from the bottom edge of the screen to the center of the screen. I saw there are some other posts somewhat related to this topic, and different voices are saying its either very difficult or very easy to do. 
I just want to ask for some pointers on how this should be implemented. an example will be very helpful!

Thank you

Comment: heyy,did u resolve this ??I'm looking for similar thing.could u please help me ??

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem in one of my apps. I overcame this by setting the visibility to true in onAnimationStart of the animation listener:

```
    TranslateAnimation show_menu_buttons = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0, 
                                                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0, 
                                                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1, 
                                                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0);
    show_menu_buttons.setDuration(500);
    show_menu_buttons.setFillAfter(true);       
    show_menu_buttons.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
        {
            menu_buttons.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
        {

        }
    });
```